# Rails Wrong Fingerprint in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am trying to deploy my rails app to a production server - Ubuntu / Apache 2.2 / Passenger. I have big problems getting the asset pipeline to work.

The links that the app produces

```
 <img alt="Icon_twitter" src="/assets/icon_twitter-d7c26009c533fda2272d24ebd9e1d008.png" />
```

do not match with the ones that the precompilation creates.
If I ssh into the server and run a production rails console (`RAILS_ENV=production rails 
c`), then

```
foo = ActionView::Base.new
foo.image_tag('icon_twitter.png')
```

gives the correct src url /assets/icon_twitter-98c828459b123bb84cf09f0070d95757.png,
which I can also access via browser 
http://www.ip-to-server.com/assets/icon_twitter-98c828459b123bb84cf09f0070d95757.png,
so the basic apache configuration should be right.

What went wrong? Where can I find help on why these fingerprints do not match?

I am using Rails 3.2.5 on Ruby 1.8.7., my config following `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` taken from `config = Rails.configuration`:

```
config.cache_classes: true
config.consider_all_requests_local: false
config.action_controller.perform_caching: true
config.serve_static_assets: false
config.assets.compress: true
config.assets.compile: false
config.assets.digest: true
```

Comment: Did you restart the server (`touch tmp/restart`)?

Comment: the fingerprints are usually md5 hashes of the files content. are there any dynamic values in there, like generated dates, or versions?

Comment: @PinnyM I restarted the server via ` sudo service apache2 restart
` from bash - I guess this is also okay?

Comment: @phoet No, just normal pngs.. that should not change

Comment: Solution: Turns out, that the static error page (`/public/500.html`) contains references to icons etc. with old fingerprints... How is this supposed to work, to include image assets in public static content.